# Programmatically change webform confirmation page

Tags: 8, webforms

I've looked at the other similar questions but they don't answer this precise issue.

In my use case, a webform is displayed on an arbitrary entity page (such as "activity/xx"). (This is not a 'node' entity type.)

When completed I want the user to be returned to this page with no message, but we don't know what the value of "xx" is going to be when the webform is created, and the work is going to be done by non-technical staff.

It's possible to:

- Create the webform;
- Build the entity and select the webform;
- Note the entity ID created;
- Go back and modify the webform confirmation page;

But this is not good for non-techies. It's easier if they're told to go to the settings page and add a handler.

I just need to force the confirmation redirect to reload the current page.

I could probably manage if I could use tokens in the confirmation page URL, or in the settings handler but I see nothing that says I can and my testing hasn't worked.

I know I can get the source entity in a handler in the back end, so I ought to be able to jump there. I just don't want to break anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When completed I want the user to be returned to this page **with no message**
>
> I just need to force the confirmation redirect to reload the current
>   page.

The following should do the trick:

[image]

---

Better yet:

[image]

Comment: Webforms is just too much :-) that looks great, thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: Note that this does **NOT** answer your original question, so for the benefit of people finding this page in the future I'd recommend that you update the question.